# Maven Bower configuration - jquery-nestable repository doesn't exist anymore

Tags: jquery, git, maven, bower

I have been given project to import it uses smartadmin template, which have `jquery-nestable` entry in `bower.json`. Problem is that `jquery-nestable` doesn't exist anymore, I checked using `bower install jquery-nestable` in `cmd` and I got:

> Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/thesabbir/jquery-nestable.git", exit code of #128 remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/thesabbir/jquery-nestable.git/' not found

How to solve this problem now, without bower I would just download CSS and JS file and put it css folder in project, but how to proceed with bower?

Comment: The Git repository which the bower script is referencing does not exist.  I got a 404 error when I tried to access it.  Google still has this page cached from December 2014, so it appears that it died recently.

Comment: Yes, I know that, it was replaced by https://libraries.io/bower/nestable2 , but entry     "nestable2": "~1.2.3", creates a folder nestable2, project need folder jquery-nestable to run, how can I fix this project to work using this new repository or perhaps just downloaded js and css files ?